# Klystron to klystron cascade

Tags: power, amplifier, rf, microwave

I have been studying and working with RF for quite some time. I do not yet have much knowledge on microwave devices, amplifiers and oscillators like magnetrons and klystrons.

I know that the klystron is basically the amplifier. My question is, can we feed the output of one klystron to another klystron? Like instead of feeding the output of one klystron through a coaxial cable into the input of another klystron, instead of feeding it to an antenna?

If not possible, why? If possible, how would the things be? What would be the differences between using 2 or 3 devices together in this way instead of a single device.

Note. The thought has been in my head for quite some time, as I was thinking, how would the mW level power from low power ICs, PLLs, VCOs and others, be amplified sufficiently to be broadcasted. I am thinking of more than 100 kW of power. I also wish to work on making klystrons myself in about a year, given that I know it’s not so simple. So I was thinking, if 1 klystron would have about 30 dB gain, another would add another 30 dB, so I would not have to worry about perfecting everything and getting the state of the art kind of gain from a single klystron.

Comment: You know that a klystron is a vacuum tube, right? Making your own requires special equipment and knowledge of glassblowing...

Comment: Yes, I know that it would be quite a work. But for now I am concerned about the cascade issue.

Comment: @shafiik you couple the klystron's output into a waveguide; if this is surprising to you, then you need to study more about basic RF devices and less about klystron cascades.

Comment: @shafik There's a nice overview [here](https://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/slacpubs/7500/slac-pub-7731.pdf) from about 1998 by Stanford Uni. In it, you'll find that there are quite a few ways of combining klystrons. Please read it carefully. It's a pretty good overview.

Comment: @marcus muller, yes, need to learn a lot about RF and microwave yet. i know the term waveguide, but little knowledge. so hopefully, you mean that through the waveguide, output of one klystron can be fed into input of another? and is this done normally? (otherwise how would so very low power from electronic devices be amplified to the hundreds of KWs of power, with each klystron having a gain of about 40-60 db?)

Comment: @jonk, Thank you for the effort and help. Very insightful in some ways. However, i am actually trying to know about just feeding input of one klystron to input of another to get a higher gain. The document is actually concerned about state of the art research regarding how to increase the output power, while i am concerned about what the relatively simpler and straightforward existent methods are to get a higher to higher gain; since electronic devices usually produce very low power (mWs).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.